# XUL - menuitem not displaying child labels on Linux

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I am dynamically populating a XUL `menu` using Javascript, and it works just fine on Windows. But when I tested it on Linux, all the `menuitem`s were blank - no `label`s were displayed.

This is how the `outerHTML` of the `menu` looks;

```
<menu xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" id="my-menu" label="Test Menu">
    <menupopup>
        <menuitem>
            <label value="Option 1" flex="4"/>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem>
             <label value="Option 2" flex="4"/>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem closemenu="none">
            <label value="Option 3" flex="2"/>
            <label value="3.333" align="end"/>
        </menuitem>
    </menupopup>
</menu>
```

Here's this `menu` on Windows:

[image: Windows]

And here's the same `menu` on Linux:

[image: Linux]

The same problem occurs on a Mac, as well.

Here's the code I use to create the `menu`;

```
var createLabel = function(document, menuitem, l) {
    if(!document || !document.createElement || 
       !menuitem || !menuitem.appendChild || 
       !l || !l.value) {
        return;
    }

    var label = document.createElement('label');

    for(var i in l) {
         if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(l, i) && l[i]) {
             label.setAttribute(i, l[i]);
         }
    }

    menuitem.appendChild(label);
};

var createMenuItem = function(document, menupopup, item) {
    if(!document || !document.createElement || 
       !menupopup || !menupopup.appendChild || 
       !item || !item.label) {
        return;
    }

    var menuitem = document.createElement('menuitem');

    createLabel(document, menuitem, item.label);

    if(item.sub_labels && item.sub_labels.length) {
        for(var i=0; i<item.sub_labels.length; ++i) {
            createLabel(document, menuitem, item.sub_labels[i]);
        }
    }

    if(item.command && typeof item.command === 'function') {
         menuitem.addEventListener('command', item.command, false);
    }

    if(item.attr) {
         for(var i in item.attr) {
             if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item.attr, i) && item.attr[i]) {
                 menuitem.setAttribute(i, item.attr[i]);
             }
         }
    }

    menupopup.appendChild(menuitem); 
};

var createMenu = function(document, id, label, items, attr) {
    if(!document || !document.createElement ||
       typeof id !== 'string' || !id.length || 
       typeof label !== 'string' || !label.length || 
       !items || !items.length) {
        return null;
    }

    var menu = document.createElement('menu'),
        menupopup = document.createElement('menupopup');

    menu.setAttribute('id', id);
    menu.setAttribute('label', label);

    for(var i=0; i<items.length; ++i) {
        createMenuItem(document, menupopup, items[i]);
    }

    if(attr) {
        for(var i in attr) {
            if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(attr, i) && attr[i]) {
                menu.setAttribute(i, attr[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    menu.appendChild(menupopup);
    return menu;
};
```

This is how I called the function in my case;

```
createMenu(document, 'my-menu', 'Test Menu', [
    {
        label: {
            value: 'Option 1',
            flex: '4'
        },
        command: function() {
            console.log('Option 1 fired');
        }
    },
    {
        label: {
            value: 'Option 2',
            flex: '4'
        },
        command: function() {
            console.log('Option 2 fired');
        }
    },
    {
        label: {
            value: 'Option 3',
            flex: '2'
        },
        sub_labels: [
            {
                value: '3.333',
                align: 'end'
            }
        ],
        attr: {
            closemenu: 'none'
        }
    }
]);
```

The XUL above is the one I got on calling `outerHTML` on the `menu` created using `createMenu`. Also, I've tried both `createElementNS` and `createElement`, it doesn't really matter - both give the exact same result.

Now, I know that usually the `label` attribute of the `menuitem` is set and that method works for me in all cases. But, I want to show two `label`s in one of the `menuitem`s with one label aligned to the end.

Just setting the `label` attribute doesn't allow such alignment.

So the question is, why doesn't this markup work on Linux but works on Windows? And what can I do to make it work such that I have the desired alignment.

Comment: Looks like that Unity menu extension messes things up (not part of Firefox, but Ubuntu). You should probably file a bug [on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/globalmenu-extension)

Comment: @nmaier I just tested on a Mac as well, same problem on the Mac. So, it couldn't be an Ubuntu only problem.

Comment: Reproducible, self-contained example code, or it didn't happen ;) No really, you need to provide actual code if you want people to help you figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: @nmaier I added the code I used.